# Генерация карт для стратегической игры, с особыми условиями

Tags: разработка-игр, процедурная-генерация

Занимаюсь разработкой генерации карт подобную той, что есть в игре Dune 2 - игра жанра RTS, в ней есть три основных материала поверхности: песок, камень и пряность. Песок является просто поверхностью для передвижения, на камне можно строить, а пряность является основным и единственным добываемым ресурсом.

Собственно, для каждого игрока обязательно наличие, и некоторой площади камня, и некоторой площади пряности.
Так как без наличия индивидуального пространства с подобными материалами, игра для этого игрока будет почти невозможной.

Потому столкнулся со следующей задачей:
Необходимо создать генератор, который бы позволил такое сотворить. К примеру указываем трех игроков и он создает произвольно эти материалы для этих игроков и остальное заполняет песком.
Так же важно уточнить, что пряность не должна быть впритык к камню, а должна быть что-то вроде отдельного островка. Так же, камень должен быть максимально плоским (не вытянутым как полоска), так как строить на тонкой полоске будет не удобно.

Прошу посоветовать какие-нибудь алгоритмы или статьи для решения этой задачи, сам лишь работал с обычным шумом и собирал лабиринты, а тут задача все-таки немного другая.
Подойдет и англоязычный контент.

Comment: Я немного поправил терминологию - вы же имеете ввиду карты для миссий/сражений, а не мир

Comment: @Kromster, да, так даже лучше. В связи с процессом разработки в голове крутится класс World который дословно перевел как мир.

Comment: Пробовали поискать что-то самостоятельно? К примеру первые же ссылки: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/ Да и вообще там куча полезного: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html

Comment: Хотя в вашем случае можно обойтись и квадратами, разделив территорию на равные большие части по кол-ву игроков и уже внутри которых сгенерировать под-территории нужного типа. Заодно будет легче считать площадь карты, которая необходима, чтобы хватало ресурсов и пространства.